# How to overcome problems with a password requiring at transfering a file from a Linux Centos 7 to a Linux Synology?

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer

I try to transfer a file from a Linux Centos 7 machine to a Linux Synology. No problems are with using the `scp` command with this way: `scp example1.txt user@10.10.1.1`, where a password will be prompted afterwards as expected. But this is a problem when making this command as a part of a bash-script — the password prompting will bother. However, there is a way to overcome it, for example, to use a pair of generated keys: private and public with the RSA algorithm. This thing is implemented by the following commands: `ssh-keygen -t rsa` that generates a pair of the keys, and `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@10.10.1.1` that copies a public key to the remote machine. If gets it done, for example, for two Centos 7 machine so all is okay: the commands `ssh user@10.10.1.1` and `scp example1.txt user@10.10.1.1` work okay without the password prompting. But it is a problem if one of the Linux machine is Synology.

**Question**

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a permissions issue on the Synology. (The `ssh` tool is rightly paranoid about a third party being able to subvert the key-based authentication process.)

Taking suggestions from [How do I sign in to DSM with RSA key pairs via SSH?](https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_to_log_in_to_DSM_with_key_pairs_as_admin_or_root_permission_via_SSH_on_computers) here is the important part:

- Go to Control Panel > User & Group (for DSM 7.0 and above) or User (for DSM 6.2.4) > Advanced > User Home, and tick Enable user home service.
- Make sure the "homes" shared folder is using the default permissions. Non-admin users must not be granted any Read or Write permissions.

If you have the "homes" folder with non-standard permissions then the `ssh` server will distrust the certificate you've installed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.